# Change owner and group of every file directory

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I am trying to change owner, group and permissions of every file in directories:

```
%w(/etc/nginx/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/ /var/l0g/nginx/).each do |path|
  directory path do
    owner "owner1"
    group "group1"
    mode '0755'
  end
end
```

however it only changes values of directories, specified in `%w()`, i was expecting this do be recursive especially with `directory` keyword.

How can i make this script change owner, group and permission of all files in specified dirs including directories themselves?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

There is a `recursive` property for the `directory` resource which [is documented](https://docs.chef.io/resources/directory/#properties) as such:

> `recursive`
> **Ruby Type**: `true`, `false` | Default Value: `false`
>
> Create parent directories recursively, or delete directory and all children recursively. For the owner, group, and mode properties, the value of this property applies only to the leaf directory.

As such, there is no builtin way to recursively set the permissions of all files within a directory. This would also NOT be a good idea in any case as your `mode` of `755` would mark all configuration files as executable for everyone. As nginx configuration files are generally not intended to be executable, this would likely do the wrong thing!

Still, if you absolutely want to do this, you could write a bit of Ruby in a [`ruby_block`](https://docs.chef.io/resources/ruby_block/) resource, such as

```rb
require 'fileutils'

%w(/etc/nginx/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/ /var/l0g/nginx/).each do |path|
  ruby_block "Set recursive permissions for #{path}" do
    block do
      FileUtils.chmod_R(0755, path)
      FileUtils.chown_R("owner1", "group1", path)
    end
  end
end
```

A slightly more "correct" version would be:

```rb
%w(/etc/nginx/ /etc/nginx/conf.d/ /var/l0g/nginx/).each do |path|
  ruby_block "Set recursive permissions for #{path}" do
    block do
      FileUtils.chmod_R("u=rw+X,go=r+X", path)
      FileUtils.chown_R("owner1", "group1", path)
    end
  end
end
```

Here, we use a symbolic mode description instead of the strictly numeric one. This allows us to use the `X` specification rather than just `x`. The chmod specification reads here:

- For the `u`ser (i.e. owner), set the `r`ead and `w`rite bits. If the file is a directory or currently has the e`x`ecute bit set, the the execute bit.
- For the `g`roup and `o`thers, set just the `r`ead bit. If the file is a directory or currently has the e`x`ecute bit set, the the execute bit.

With this, all directories will have the execute/search bit set, and only those files who previously had the execute bit set will retain it (but no new files fill gain the execute bit).

As some final notes:

- As `/etc/nginx/conf.d` is already included in `/etc/nginx`, you can omit it from the list.
- Instead of `/var/l0g/nginx/` (with a "zero" character in the path), you likely mean `/var/log/nginx/` (with a small o) instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from *@Holger Just* already covers the implications of changing permissions/ownership. Other than that, Chef being a *configuration as code* tool, is very efficient in managing the state of defined resources. Hence, using it to alter resources such as files/directories not directly managed by it, cannot guarantee idempotent actions.

Taking all this into consideration, one option is to run the relevant Linux commands using [script](https://docs.chef.io/resources/script/) or [execute](https://docs.chef.io/resources/execute/) resource.

Example using `execute` resource:

```rb
execute 'change nginx paths ownership' do
  command 'chown --recursive owner1:group1 /etc/nginx/ /var/log/nginx/'
end

execute 'change nginx paths permissions' do
  command 'chmod --recursive 0755 /etc/nginx/ /var/log/nginx/'
end
```